Where does Rambam say: "The risk of a wrong decision is preferable to the terror of indecision"?
BH
Hi according to https://www.brainyquote.com/authors/maimonides-quotes
Rambam said the quote “The risk of a wrong decision is preferable to the terror of indecision.”
Where does he say this though?

The (possibly alleged) Rambam quote "The risk of a wrong decision is preferable to the terror of indecision" is widely attributed to Rambam on a huge number of Internet sites. I will stick my neck out here and opine that this is not a genuine quote.

If indecision means no decision, isn't it sometimes better?  Keep the status quo for now.

Saw on one random website that its allegedly in "guide to the perplexed, 76."

@Shababnik I also saw the guide to the perplexed, 76 citation. I could not square that with the Friedlander or Pines translations of the Guide.
